# How likely is Yusri to get me an omniscience effect, if I have Krark's Thumb out?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, probability

The new card [Yusri, Fortune's Flame](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Yusri%2C%20Fortune%27s%20Flame) has the clause, that if you win 5 flips off it's attack trigger ability, you can cast any card in your hand, *for free!*.

> Whenever Yusri, Fortune’s Flame attacks, choose a number between 1 and 5. Flip that many coins. For each flip you win, draw a card. For each flip you lose, Yursi deals 2 damage to you. **If you won five flips this way, you may cast spells from your hand this turn without paying their mana costs.**

<sub>emphasis mine</sub>

Normally this gives you a 1/32 chance (1 in 2 to the power of 5), but what happens if you have [Krark's Thumb](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Krark%27s%20Thumb) out?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**The probability to win all 5 coin flips with Krark's Thumb is 0.75^5, or 23.7%, up from 3.1% without Krark's Thumb.**

Normally, you would have a 50% chance to win a single coin flip. Since multiple coin flips are independent of each other, you can just multiply their probabilities, so you get a (0.5)^5 = 0.031 (3.1%) probability to have 5 coin flips go your way.

Each Krark's Thumb essentially halves the probability of losing a coin flip. For one Thumb, It goes from 50% to 25%, so the chance to win goes to 1 - 0.25 = 0.75. The probability to win 5 such coin flips is (0.75)^5 = 0.237, or 23.7%

Comment: This is a clever way to do it. I didn't twig the extra thumb halves the failure rate. Much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

For each of the two coins that you flip with [Krak's Thumb](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Krak%27s%20Thumb) you have an extra chance to win.

This is not the same as flipping double, and keeping the best 5.

Here is the [anydice code](https://anydice.com/program/228f4) I used to calculate this

```
output 5 d [highest 1 of 2d2] -5 named "Flips won"
```

| Dice rolled | Probability to get *at least* that many |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 100.00% |
| 1 | 99.90% |
| 2 | 98.44% |
| 3 | 89.65% |
| 4 | 63.28% |
| 5 | 23.73% |

So 23.73% of the time you get to cast your cards for free!